# Get "joined" results without use "->join()" in doctrine

Tags: php, join, doctrine-orm

I am newbie in doctrine (and advance in cakephp)

I have "users" hasMany "projects" hasMany "tasks", how get users and related tasks without write the "->joins()"?

Thanks,
Celso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have properly did all the mappings, then you don't have to use the join. You can just call.

`$users->getProjects();` and loop through the projects and get `$projects->getTasks();` . There won't be any direct relation b/w users and tasks.